# PHP email submit form receiver not receiving the correct sendr email address

Tags: php, forms, email

Im trying to figure out the problem with the PHP code for submit form, im doing for my friend.  It is sending the emails through, but the problem is that the receiver gets a very odd email address. I am attaching an image to have a closer look.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php 
    $error = false;
    $sent = false;

    if(isset($_Post['name'])) {
        if(empty($_Post['name']) || empty($_Post['email']) ||  empty($_Post['comments'])) {
            $error = true;
        } else {

        $to = "linardsberzins@gmail.com";

        $name = trim($_Post['name']);
        $email = trim($_Post['email']);
        $comments = trim($_Post['comments']);

        $subject = "Contact Form";

        $messages =  "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:" . $name . "\r\n";
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

        if($mailsent) {
            $sent = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Many thanks [image: odd email displayed]

Comment: what you are getting email in email ?

Comment: Do you mean `$_POST` rather than `$_Post`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be like this `Sender <HIS@EXAMPLE.COM>`:

```
 $headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thats the one, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the headers to the email, like this from [PHP mail Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) example 2

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If you want it to be from an email with a name, this would work

```
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your headers

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: $replyEmail\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

The From: header should include an email address as well as the name, something like

```
"From:My Display Name<mydisplayname@gmail.com>\r\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $error = false;
    $sent = false;

    if(isset($_Post['name'])) {
        if(empty($_Post['name']) || empty($_Post['email']) ||  empty($_Post['comments'])) {
            $error = true;
        } else {

        $to = "linardsberzins@gmail.com";

        $name = trim($_Post['name']);
        $email = trim($_Post['email']);
        $comments = trim($_Post['comments']);

        $subject = "Contact Form";

        $messages =  "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <sender@example.com>' . "\r\n";
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

        if($mailsent) {
            $sent = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Try this. just change the header.

```
$headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <sender@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This was not an error.. If you provide `SENDER EMAIL` then it will display the senders email address instead of this.. Otherwise it will take our hosting address.