# PHP Contact Form not sending (long loading time then reports to have sent but no mail)

Tags: php, email, contacts, contact-form

I'm using the same code as this stackoverflow question [Simple PHP Contact Form Not Sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232662/simple-php-contact-form-not-sending) Having the same problem, except their problem was solved by checking their spam box, where as mine is empty. I'm running Ubuntu, have installed PHP, running the webpage locally from Apache 2. The only hint I have is that Chrome loads for maybe a minute before I am returned with a "Thank You" PHP page. What should I try first?

**html**

```
<form action="contactus.php" method="POST" class="create">
 <fieldset>
<legend align="center">Please fill out details below and click "Submit"</legend>
<div>
 <label for="fullname" class="fixedwidth">Full Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="input2"/>
</div><br/>
<div>
 <label for="email" class="fixedwidth">Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input2"/>
</div><br/>
  <div>
 <label for="subject" class="fixedwidth">Subject</label>
 <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input2"/>
</div><br/>
<div>
<label for="details" class="fixedwidth">Body</label>
 <textarea id="details" name="details" cols="62" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="buttonarea">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

**php**

```
<?php 
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$details = $_POST['details'];
$formcontent = "From: $fullname \n Message: $details";
$recipient = "johndoe1@email.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214875/php-email-submit/12215023#12215023

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU Sorry I'm not exactly sure how the problem you linked relates to mine. Their emails were sending.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

Install SMTP server  locally or use an external one.
Configure your php.ini properly to use this SMTP server.

postfix, qmail, sendmail are examples of SMTP servers.
 
I think qmail is the most lightweight one.
swiftmailer is just a PHP library for mailing to make programming job easier not a server.
swiftmailer is written in PHP, but an SMTP sever works on the socket layer and as far as I know they are written with languages like c or c++.

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about the other recommendation I've been given. I'm guessing that postfix is a SMTP server, so I should use postfix? I don't need something like swiftmailer?

Comment: I've installed postfix. Is it true that I shouldn't have to modify the php.ini as I am running the SMPT from Localhost? I am now returned the same "thankyou" php but this time without the excessive loading. So something is happening. I've been playing around with different postfix configurations, but still nothing.

Comment: This is the only instance of SMPT I could find in the .ini but I don't think it applies to me as im using linux and it seems to indicate these details are for windows[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25  @Amir Noori

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't configured and admin mail server myself. so I can't help you more.
Search for tutorials online,I'm sure you can fix it. but if you still have problems, you can use Google's or other free SMTP servers for sending mails with PHP scripts.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

please install and configure postfix in your ubuntu server, then use php mail() function to send email.

Comment: Put this in the comments.

Comment: @Neo Thanks, I just installed postfix with no configuration and now I get an "error" PHP message instead of the usual loading and "thank you". Now I just need to figure out how to configure the thing. Will be back if I get it working.

Comment: @Neo Any hints on what parameters need to be configured to get the outbound mail working?